# Download Settings for Text Files in JSF PrimeFaces

Tags: linux, primefaces, jsf-2, ascii, tomcat6

We have a web application hosted on Linux server running Apache Tomcat 6. The application provides a feature of downloading text files through fileDownload tag of PrimeFaces. If we run the application on Eclipse and "download" the file (located on my Windows 7 machine) through the web browser, everything works fine. But when we deploy the application on the Linux server and download the file and open it in Notepad, it doesn't have any line breaks i.e. everything is shown in one line.

Notepad++ shows the file as it should be but we need the same for Notepad too. **Is there any setting for Linux or PrimeFaces to make sure that the file transferred to the client side with line breaks for Notepad?**

I have Googled but could not find anything related to this.

Comment: `everything works fine` - did you try opening the file with Notepad in this case? The file likely has LF line endings, whereas Notepad expects CR+LF.

Comment: That's the problem of LF missing but I don't know how to fix it. I edited the file again by first pasting the content in MS Word and back to the text file. Put it on the server. When I opened it through the SSH **File Transfer Window**, Notepad worked perfectly (it was strange for me). I need to know how to download through the application and not lose the LF

Comment: maybe ssh file transfer has some 'correction mechanism' built-in

Comment: That could be the case